# Homebrew and Permission denied issue

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

I try to compile and install [libapreq2](http://httpd.apache.org/apreq/) via Homebrew package manager.

```
brew create http://www.apache.si//httpd/libapreq/libapreq2-2.13.tar.gz
```

The content of the `libapreq2.rb` formula is as follows.

```
require 'formula'

class Libapreq2 < Formula
  url 'http://www.apache.si//httpd/libapreq/libapreq2-2.13.tar.gz'
  homepage ''
  md5 'c11fb0861aa84dcc6cd0f0798b045eee'

  # depends_on 'cmake'

  def install
    system "./configure", "--disable-debug", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    # system "cmake . #{std_cmake_parameters}"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

I proceed with

```
brew install -vd libapreq2
```

but unfortunately the compilation ended with errors.

```
mkdir: /usr/include/apache2/apreq2: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-pkgincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/mod_apreq2.so /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_apreq2.so
install: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_apreq2.so: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-pkglibLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Brew try to install some files outside the `/usr/local/Cellar/libapreq2/` directory. I wonder how to manage these "permission denied" issues. I tried as root user (i.e., `sudo brew install libapreq2`), but if I later want to remove the library, only the files in `/usr/local/Cellar/libapreq2/` are removed.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package *really* shouldn't install anything in the system includes in **/usr/include**. The place for homebrew packaged includes is **/usr/local/include** (as symlinks into **Cellar**). You'll just have to adjust your `./configure` invocation to use `#{prefix}/include` for the includes (probably `--incdir` or something very similar).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar/libapreq2/
```

It works for me!